# how to calculate total number of combinations for 4*3 matrix where 2 elements in matrix are not present

Tags: java, matrix, combinations, permutation

below is the format of the matrix. and no diagonal combinations of letters is allowed ,only vertical and horizontal combinations are allowed.
Can anyone suggest how to calculate the number of combinations required for a particular level.
example: if i say level is 1 then , only 1 letter combination is allowed i.e. A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I i.e. 10 combinations
if i say level is 2 then possible combinations are AA,BB,AB,AD,BC,BE,... and so on  so total 36 combinations for level 2.
Like that if input is any level  number given, then how do i calculate the possible number of combinations ?

```
A   B   C
D   E   F
G   H   I
    J
```

I tried using this formula :

```
(n!/(r!(n-r)!)
```

but it doesnt calculate properly from level 2 onwards.
note : on both sides of J no letter is present.

Please suggest.

Comment: What have yout tried so far?

Comment: i have wriiten the code below

Answer (score -1):

@Thientvse 
This is the code that i coded... it gives correct output...can you please tell me whether my code is correct and whether it will satisfy all test cases for this scenario

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Game {
    public static int combinationCounts(int input1){
        ArrayList<String> mainalternatestring = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> mainverticalstring = new ArrayList<String>();
        String sb = "ABC#DEF#GHI# J ";
        String a=null,b=null,c=null,nw=null;

        int mainindex = 0,counter,totalcount=10,index=0,mainindex_duplicate=0,count=1;

        if(input1 > 1 && input1 <= 4){
            while(mainindex != 11){
                int level =  0;
                counter = 0;
                count=1;
                char[] strtoworkon = new char[sb.length()];
                index=0;

                if(mainindex != 0)
                    mainindex = mainindex+1;

                for(int j = mainindex; count!= (sb.length()-mainindex) ; j++){
                    if(level == input1)
                        break;

                    if(sb.charAt(j) == '#'){
                        level++;
                        if (counter == 0){
                            mainindex_duplicate = j;  
                            counter = 1;
                        }
                    }

                    if(level <= input1){
                        strtoworkon[index] = sb.charAt(j);
                        index++;
                    }
                    count++;
                }
                mainindex = mainindex_duplicate;

                // for sideways combinations
                for(int m = 0; m <= strtoworkon.length; m++){
                    c = null;
                    if(strtoworkon[m] == ' ')
                        break;
                    if(!String.valueOf(strtoworkon).substring(m, m+(input1)).contains("#")){
                        c = String.valueOf(strtoworkon).substring(m, m+(input1));

                        if(!c.matches(".*[A-Z].*"))
                            break;

                        if(!mainalternatestring.contains(c))
                            mainalternatestring.add(c);

                    }
                }

                //for vertical combinations  
                nw = "#" + (String.valueOf(strtoworkon));
                int counter1=0;
                while(counter1 != 3){
                    c="";
                    for(int n = 0; n<= strtoworkon.length; n++){
                        if(nw.charAt(n) == '#'){
                            Character test = nw.charAt(n+counter1);

                            a = Character.toString(strtoworkon[n+counter1]).trim();
                            if(a.contains("#"))
                                break;
                            c = a+c;
                            c.trim();
                        }
                    }
                    if(!mainverticalstring.contains(c) && c.length() == input1)
                        mainverticalstring.add(c);
                    counter1++;
                }

                if(mainindex == 11)
                    break;
            }
            totalcount = totalcount + (2*mainalternatestring.size()) + (2*mainverticalstring.size());
        }
        return totalcount;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

         Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            int output = 0;
            int ip1 = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine().trim());
            output = combinationCounts(ip1);
            System.out.println(String.valueOf(output));
    }
}
```